# Where is the source that the spiritual realms are mirrored or reversed?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, zohar, arizal

I heard this from a ma'amar back in yeshiva, but I cannot remember the source. In Ezekiel's vision of the merkavah, the supernal "chariot," the face of the lion is to the right while the face of the ox is to the left. Obviously, the lion should be on the left and the tame ox on the side of chesed. It's explained in Tanya, [igeret hakodesh 20](https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7965/jewish/Epistle-20.htm), that the spiritual worlds are like an inverted seal. So too, the merkavah is also reversed, but I can't recall the source.

Comment: Tikunei Zohar 13b : Brain, it says of it The face of the lion to the right, that's the side the Menorah shines.  Heart - And the face of the bull to the left, and that's where the Table is set, because the heart is to the left...
מוחא, עליה אתמר ופני אריה אל הימין, ותמן מנרתא דליק, לבא ופני שור מהשמאל, ותמן פתורא מתתקנא, בגין דלבא איהו לשמאלא, ...

Comment: It seems interesting that we find that each hemisphere of the brain controls the opposite side of the body, and the Kabbalists compare the body to creation as a whole.